# Operating systems for some azure services

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache, azure-mysql-database

I was looking at Azure documentation but I couldn't find what type of operating system does Azure for MySQL and Azure Redis Cache use. I assume that for redis it should be a must to use Ubuntu but can't find any details about underlying infrastructure. I may have missed it so if you can please refer me to it.

I want to know what are the difference between my current environment and Azure managed DBs and also what control I would lose if moving to managed instances as opposed to the many benefits that I would gain before going that way.

Comment: The whole idea behind managed services is that the underlying infrastructure is hidden for the consumer. That is why you won't find any documentation about it.

Comment: Also, it's Windows and Service Fabric. But you shouldn't care, because if you care, you shouldn't use a managed, hosted service, you should roll your own.

Comment: Not sure about MySQL but Azure Redis Cache uses Windows OS.

Comment: @GauravMantri thx .. that's why I wanted to make sure cause windows and redis are the worst combination .. redis site itself doesn't recommend any non-unix based systems

Comment: @PeterBons and evilSnobu, yeah you are both right .. but my customer was advised to move to managed services and I wanted to see what we are losing. for example, for redis, if it uses windows then I want to keep using my own instance if the managed instance uses windows since it has many problems and only old versions are available (unlike unix-based).